# need css to js implementation

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors, implementation

I have one issue to be solved.

see the link below.

[pop up modal](https://codepen.io/LFeh/pen/oEula)

html is as follows....

```
<div class="wrap">

<a href="#modal-one" class="btn btn-big">Modal!</a>

</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="modal-one" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-header">
  <h2>Modal in CSS?</h2>
  <a href="#" class="btn-close" aria-hidden="true">×</a>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <p>One modal example here! :D</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <a href="#" class="btn">Nice!</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<!-- /Modal -->
```

When the Modal button is clicked the pop-up dialog appears with animation. But I want to get this done using jquery. I don't know much css, so I am not able to get anything. Can any one help into this?

and the css is in th link

Comment: follow this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

Comment: they are simply using :target css selector to do this... just delete those css and intialize it using jquery code

Comment: Ssahil, can you help me in this? as I am very new to css... but want to use this only using js...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Things to follow to convert this css to js click event code:
>
> 1 Just remove or comment the :target css from the scss file.

```
  // &:target {
  //   // Active animate in modal
  //   &:before {
  //     display: block;
  //   }
  //   .modal-dialog {
  //     .translate(0, 0);
  //     top: 20%;
  //   }
  // }
```

> 2. Write the Js Code

```
// With JAvascript =D
$('a[href="#modal-one"]').click(function(){
  $('.modal').addClass('open');

});
$('.close').click(function(){
  $('.modal').removeClass('open');

});
```

> 3. Some additional Css - Added for opening popup logic on click.

```
*Additional Css Added */
.modal.open .modal-dialog {
  transform:translate(0,0);
  top:20%;
     }
.modal.open::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Here is the updated **[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/sahildhir_1/pen/LyGZwa)**

Comment: thanks.. it solved the issue... also I studied the same and got the concept.. but will look into it later

Answer (score 0):

Check if [this](http://jsfiddle.net/1aeur58f/1/) bootstrap model meets your need

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    jQuery('#mymodal').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: yes... but want to use the modal shared in question

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sample with jquery.This code will open your modal if it's closed or it will close if it's opened already.

```
 $("#kullaniciModal").modal("toggle");

 <div class="modal fade" id="kullaniciModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Kullanıcılar</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Kapat</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```